# Grails logging with logback.groovy

Tags: grails, logback

In a Grails 4 application, I'm getting messages like this in my log:

```
2020-06-01 09:43:26.738  INFO --- [ XNIO-1 task-30] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : No messages received after 147302 ms. Closing WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=f4jrcctz].
```

I'm not interested in anything other than warnings or errors for that package, and thought I would achieve this by having this in logback.groovy:

`logger('o.s.w.s', WARN)`

(This is to cover both o.s.w.s.m and o.s.w.s.c).

But the INFO messages are still appearing. What's wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: Does it work if you spell out the package instead of abbreviating?

Comment: I thought that WAS the name of the package! I've only seen it like that. I'll try and find out what it stands for (it's to do with Stomp).

Comment: I think `o.s.w.s` is `org.springframework.web.socket`, as in `org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and that is the answer. It's pretty obvious, really, when looking at it, but I had no idea that loggers abbreviated the package names. Of course, they have to or you would never see the all-important class name because of the sheer length of the text. I live and learn!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.